# React state (useState) doesn't update with fetched data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

**Background**

I have a star rating system. When a user has already rated the content, I want them to be able to see their previous rating when the page loads.

I am able to fetch the rating data for the user and I have a set initial state for the star rating, just in case there isn't any rating yet.

**The Goal**

The goal is to set the initial state for the star rating with a value of `0`. When the previously-stored rating value is fetched, I want the initial state value to update to the fetched rating value.

**The Problem**

Currently, when the page loads, the star rating value says it's `undefined`, even though the stored rating value is fetched and appears in my console. I'm pretty sure this is happening because the variable is being called before the data query has finished. Unfortunately, it doesn't update when it does finish.

**Code**

In the code below, `articleRating`  is the fetched rating value

```js
// data query
const {
    data: { feedback, id: feedbackId, rating: articleRating },
    status: feedbackStatus,
  } = useGetFeedback(slug as string, "lesson")

// setting initial state for star rating
const [starsSelected, selectStar] = useState(0)

// Updating the rating value to show previously stored rating
useEffect(() => {
    if (articleRating !== null || articleRating !== "undefined") {
      console.log("rating value: ", articleRating)
      selectStar(articleRating)
    }
 }, [])
```

In the code above, I'm using the `useEffect` hook because I get an error message saying there are infinite renders without it and the page breaks.

Thanks in advance for any advice! ✌️

Comment: Are you doing any `useEffect` inside `useGetFeedback `?

Comment: No, it's all separate. I'm not sure if the` useEffect` is the best approach. I'm currently using it because I get an error message saying there are infinite renders without it and the page breaks.

Comment: Ideally you should pass `articleRating` inside dependency array . There are chances that is already re-render. and empty `[]` represent it runs only one time . Try this `[articleRating]`

Comment: What do you mean by `star rating value says it's undefined`? you have `articleRating` and `starsSelected`

Comment: It works... I feel so dumb. :D Thank you! You just saved me a few hours! @ShubhamVerma

Comment: Cool. Anytime : -)

Answer (score 0):

Your `useEffect` is only being run on the first render, you should add `articleRating` to the dependency array in the second parameter, then it will run only when that variable gets updated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Would you mind giving me an example? I can't quite picture it.

Comment: Change that last line to ` }, [articleRating])`