# How to update the react state variable with fetched data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have fetched a response from an API by the getCalendarData function.
Then, I have used the promise returned from this function in useEffect method, as I want to consume it on component load.
Now I am assigning the object key values received in the response in state variables, but they they are coming undefined. The state variables that I need to set are calendarHeading and calendarDescription.
Maybe I am messing around re-rendering the component, because, the when state variable "calendarSlugData" takes the value of the response, the other state variables- calendarHeading and calendarDescription should also change their values. Can someOne point out my mistake here?
Below is my code for this component:

```
const CalendarCard = (props) => {
    const { calendarModal, formData, redirectCTA, formCTA, showForm, calSlug } = props;
    let {heading, description} = props;
    const { delayTime, link, label, clickTag } = calendarModal;
    const [step, setStep] = useState(showForm ? 1 : 2);
    const [calendarThankYouData, setCalendarThankYouData] = useState({});
    
    const [calendarSlugData, setCalendarSlugData]=useState({});
    const durationInMinutes = (slotsFromQuery && !isNaN(parseInt(slotsFromQuery))) ? parseInt(slotsFromQuery) : 30;
    const calRequestType = 'CALENDAR_LEAD';

    const calculateHeading = () => {
        heading = modalType === 'Go modal' ? 'Let a Birdeye specialist show you!' : calendarSlugData.heading;
        return heading;
    };

    const calculateDescription = () => {
        description = modalType === 'Go modal' ? 'Book a personalized demo for free with a Birdeye product expert' : calendarSlugData.subHeading;
        return description;
    };
    const [calendarHeading, setCalendarHeading] = useState(step === 3 ? 'All set!' : calculateHeading());
    const [calendarDescription, setCalendarDescription] = useState(step === 3 ? 'We’re looking forward to chatting with you soon!' : calculateDescription());
    // console.log("heading value", heading);
    // console.log("description  value", description);
 
    const getCalendarData = async (calendarSlug) => {
        let calendarData = {};
        const slug = 'cal/' + calendarSlug;
        try {
            const { data } = await contentAPI.get('/calendar/page');
            const pageObj = data.filter(calendar => calendar.active && calendar.slug === slug);
            if(!isEmpty(pageObj)) calendarData = pageObj[0];
            else throw { wrongSlug:true };
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('===@@@===', e);
            throw {notFound: true};
        }
        return calendarData;
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getCalendarData(calSlug).then(calendarData => {
            console.log('calendarData is', calendarData);
            setCalendarSlugData(calendarData);
        });
        
            
    }, []);

    const [calendarObject, setCalendarObject] = useState({
        type: calType,
        durationInMinutes,
        slug: 'cal/' + calSlug,
        requestType: calRequestType,
        statusFailedHandler,
        formData: getCompleteFormData(formData), // formData is from an independent form
        handleCalendarAndSlot: (thankYouData) => {
            if (modalType === 'Go modal') autoRedirect();
            setCalendarThankYouData({...thankYouData, duration: durationInMinutes, redirectCTA, formCTA, requestType: calRequestType, modalType});
            setCalendarHeading(step === 3 ? 'All set!' : heading);
            setCalendarDescription(step === 3 ? 'We’re looking forward to chatting with you soon!' : description);
            setStep((prevState) => (prevState + 1));
        },
        formCTA,
        modalType
    });

    console.log('CalendarSlugData is', calendarSlugData);
    console.log("step is", step);
    console.log('final heading', calendarHeading);
    console.log('final description is', calendarDescription);
    
}
```

I debugged the code several times. The variables heading and description are getting set with the values from the response, but they are not getting passed into the state variables-calendarHeading and calendarDescription.
I also tried to pass a dependency- "calendarSlugData" in the useEffect dependency array, but that goes into an infinite loop. What else can I put in the dependency array here?
I even referred this post ([React state (useState) doesn't update with fetched data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63723369/react-state-usestate-doesnt-update-with-fetched-data)) on stackOverflow where the problem is similar to mine. But I have tried adding a dependency in the useEffect.

Please help!

Comment: `else throw { wrongSlug:true }` don't do that. You don't have a catch handler on the call, so any error is going to go unhandled. That being said, you never call the setters for those state values, so why are you surprised they are unchanged? The only setter you call is `setCalendarSlugData`

Comment: Have you tried adding `calSlug` to the dependency array in your `useEffect`?

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I am not facing any issues while fetching the data. I am not able to assign the fetched value to the state variables. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: "I am not facing any issues while fetching the data." you forgot to say "yet" ;) as for the rest, you'll have to set the data using the setters, re-read my earlier comment.

Comment: @JaredSmith I am calling the setters for Calendarheading and CalendarDescription in the CalendarObject which is being used later on. Apologies I missed to mention in the code block earlier. Can you point out my mistake now?

Comment: Yes @EricHasegawa, I added the calSlug to the dependency array in useEffect. It didn't help. Can you please suggest other way round?

Comment: You never call the function you set on `handleCalendarAndSlot`, so it doesn't run. Why do you have all this state anyway? None of this makes any sense. Assigning a function to something in state that modifies other state is asking for stale closure problems. This is supposed to be a component, but you aren't returning anything? I think you should take a step back and think about how you actually want to decompose your data, and what needs to *actually* go in state vs what is derived from values *in* your state.